# Homotopy of sheaves

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory

On a certain topological space $X$ I want to think about sheaves up to homotopy, i.e., homotopies in the space of sheaves over $X$, and then see what homotopy classes of sheaves I get. Is there a good reference for this I can look at? Thanks!

Comment: Key words are "homotopy sheaves" and the "h-principle". I find [Manifold Calculus and Homotopy Sheaves](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.1305) a great reference.